# GLSL Fragment Position

Tags: glsl

In my .cpp code I create a list of quads, a few of them have a flag, in the pixel shader  I check if this flag is set or not, if the flag is not set, the quad gets colored in red for example, if the flag is set, I want to decide the color of every single pixel, so if I need to colour half of the flagged quad in red and the other half in blue I can simply do something like :

```
if coordinate in quad < something color = red
else colour = blue;
```

In this way I can get half of the quad colored in blue and another half colored in red, or I can decide where to put the red color or where to put the blue one.

Imagine I've got a quad 50x50 pixels

[frag]

```
if(quad.flag == 1)
  {    
    if(Pixel_coordinate.x<25 ) gl_fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    else gl_fragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
else
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

In this case I would  expect that a quad with the flag set will get two colors per face.
I hope I have been more specific now.

thanks.

Just to add something I can't use any texture.

Ok i do this now :

Every quad has 4 textures coordinated (0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0);

I enable the texture coordinates using :

```
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(float) * 7));
```

[vert]

```
varying vec2 texCoord;

main()
{
    texCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
}
```

[frag]

```
varying vec2 texCoord;

main()
{
    float x1 = texCoord.s;
    float x2 = texCoord.t;
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(x1, x2, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I get always the yellow color so x1 =1 and x2 = 1 almost always and some quad is yellow/green.

I would expect that the texture coordinates change in the fragment shader and so I should get a gradient, am I wrong?

Comment: To *"understand"* which position (and thus what *"half"* of geometry)? The screen-space position? The world-space position? The view-space position? Which one?

Comment: What is the local position, do you mean the position of the quad in world space or what? What means *"coloring the pixels half and half"*? Does the use of this flag have any meaning for the actual question (meaning is it this flag you want to compute dynamically somehow based on *"understanding the position"*)? I have a really hard time trying to understand what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know the coordinate *within* the quad, you need to calculate it yourself.  In order to that, you'll need to create a new interpolant (call it something like `vec2 quadCoord`), and set it appropriately for each vertex, which means you'll likely also need to add it as an attribute and pass it through your vertex shader.  eg:

```
// in the vertex shader
attribute vec2 quadCoordIn;
varying vec2 quadCoord;

main() {
    quadCoord = quadCoordIn;
              :
```

You'll need to feed in this attribute in your drawing code when drawing your quads.  For each quad, the vertexes will have likely have `quadCoordIn` values of (0,0), (0,1), (1,1) and (1,0) -- you could use some other coordinate system if you prefer, but this is the easiest.

Then, in your fragment program, you can access `quadCoord.xy` to determine where in the quad you are.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your answer, just another thing, I think that if I don't enable a texture in my cpp code the texture coordinates are constant or 0 or 1  I did discover this because coloring the fragment with the texture coordinates  i get only two colors, is this correct(I mean, do I need also to enable and bind a texture or opengl will not give me the correct texture coordinates in the fragment shader?)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to *Chris Dodd*'s answer, you can also access the screen-space coordinate (in pixels, though actually pixel centers and thus `?.5`) of the currently processed fragment through the special fragment shader variable `gl_FragCoord`:

```
gl_FragColor = (gl_FragCoord.x<25.0) ? vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) : vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

But this gives you the position of the fragment in screen-space and thus relative to the lower left corner of you viewport. If you actually need to know the position inside the individual quad (which makes more sense if you want to actually color each quad half-by-half, since the "half-cut" would otherwise vary with the quad's position), then *Chris Dodd*'s answer is the correct approach.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for you answer, you are right, I need to access every simple quad so gl_FragCoord does not work for me :(