# How to correctly apply affine transformation to vertices for scenes rendered with signed distance functions

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl2

I want to render shapes using sdf, here's my

vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
in vec2 a_position;
uniform mat3 uMatrix;

void main() {
  vec2 position = (uMatrix * vec3(a_position, 1)).xy;    
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
uniform vec2 uResolution;
out vec4 outColor;

vec2 screenToWorld(vec2 screen) {
  vec2 result = 2.0 * (screen/uResolution.xy - 0.5);
  result.x *= uResolution.x/uResolution.y;
  return result;
}

void main() {

  vec2 p = screenToWorld(gl_FragCoord.xy);

  vec3 col = vec3(0.5);

  sceneColorWithSDF(col, p);

  outColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

You can see `uMatrix` is controlling translation, when I render at 0,0 it's fine, but when I render at 0.5,0.5 the vertices translate but the shapes at the scene stay at the same screen coordinates.

How can I translate vertices as well as the shapes with them?

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me [GLSL Fragment Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111325/glsl-fragment-position).

Basically i need to pass the quad coordinates as varying.

vertex shader:

```
out vec2 vQuadCoord;

void main() {
  vQuadCoord = a_position;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
in vec2 vQuadCoord;

void main() {
  // use vQuadCoord to calculate 
}
```